# Vacuum Database with laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, sqlite

I try to send a vacuum command with laravel in this way:

```
DB::raw('end transaction');
DB::raw('vacuum');
```

I read the log file, but there are no errors. When I Checking the database , it still weighs 95MB. 
So the vacuum command it was not accepted. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, all you need to do is to use `statement` instead of `raw`:

```
DB::statement('vacuum');
```

Documentation can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database)